# SELECT with RowNumber takes long to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing debug messages defined as follows:

```
id  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY
message TEXT NOT NULL
date    DATETIME NOT NULL
```

Against that, I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RowNum, * 
    FROM debug WHERE message LIKE @Filter
) AS tbl 
WHERE RowNum > (@Page*200-200) 
AND RowNum <= (@Page * 200)
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

This gives me a single page of 200 results; but with 220k entries in the table (and counting!), the filtering and row numbering takes a considerable amount of time (>30 secs).

Is there anything I can do to speed up the process of getting that page of results?

EDIT: So I have switched to VARCHAR(MAX) as proposed by Gordon; but this didn't speed the things up. The resulting execution plan of the query is as follows (I try to repaint the graphics as ASCII-Art):

```
                                       Sequence Project                        Clustered Index Scan
    SELECT <- Sort <- Filter <- Top <- (Compute Scalar) <- Segment <- Filter <- [debug].[PK_debug]
Cost: 0%       26%      0%       0%           0%             0%         2%           71%
```

or in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.2" Build="12.0.2569.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="4" StatementEstRows="16.4317" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="120" StatementSubTreeCost="0.0438369" StatementText="SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RowNum, * FROM debug WHERE message LIKE @Filter) AS tbl WHERE RowNum &gt; (@Page*200-200) AND RowNum &lt;= (@Page * 200) ORDER BY ID DESC" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x535D30B424597DBB" QueryPlanHash="0x17ABB516DFF1A1A7" RetrievedFromCache="true">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" NonParallelPlanReason="EstimatedDOPIsOne" MemoryGrant="1024" CachedPlanSize="32" CompileTime="4" CompileCPU="4" CompileMemory="248">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="512" SerialDesiredMemory="672" RequiredMemory="512" DesiredMemory="672" RequestedMemory="1024" GrantWaitTime="0" GrantedMemory="1024" MaxUsedMemory="56" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="256000" EstimatedPagesCached="16000" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="1" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="4055" EstimateCPU="0.000207573" EstimateIO="0.0112613" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="16.4317" LogicalOp="Sort" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sort" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0438369">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="id" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="message" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="date" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
              </OutputList>
              <MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="1" />
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="147" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Sort Distinct="false">
                <OrderBy>
                  <OrderByColumn Ascending="false">
                    <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="id" />
                  </OrderByColumn>
                </OrderBy>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="4055" EstimateCPU="8.8E-05" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="16.4317" LogicalOp="Filter" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Filter" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0323681">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="id" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="message" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="date" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="147" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <Filter StartupExpression="false">
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="4055" EstimateCPU="1E-05" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="100" LogicalOp="Top" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Top" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0322801">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="id" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="message" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="date" />
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="147" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <Top RowCount="false" IsPercent="false" WithTies="false">
                        <TopExpression>
                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CASE WHEN CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@Page]*(200),0) IS NULL OR CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@Page]*(200),0)&lt;(0) THEN (0) ELSE CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@Page]*(200),0) END">
                            <IF>
                              <Condition>
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Logical Operation="OR">
                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                      <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                          <Identifier>
                                            <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1007">
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Convert DataType="bigint" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                                    <Arithmetic Operation="MULT">
                                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                                        <Identifier>
                                                          <ColumnReference Column="@Page" />
                                                        </Identifier>
                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                                        <Const ConstValue="(200)" />
                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                    </Arithmetic>
                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                </Convert>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </ColumnReference>
                                          </Identifier>
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                          <Const ConstValue="NULL" />
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                      </Compare>
                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                      <Compare CompareOp="LT">
                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                          <Identifier>
                                            <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1007">
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Convert DataType="bigint" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                                    <Arithmetic Operation="MULT">
                                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                                        <Identifier>
                                                          <ColumnReference Column="@Page" />
                                                        </Identifier>
                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                                        <Const ConstValue="(200)" />
                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                    </Arithmetic>
                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                </Convert>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </ColumnReference>
                                          </Identifier>
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                          <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                      </Compare>
                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                  </Logical>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Condition>
                              <Then>
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Then>
                              <Else>
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1007">
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Convert DataType="bigint" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Arithmetic Operation="MULT">
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Column="@Page" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Const ConstValue="(200)" />
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </Arithmetic>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </Convert>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </ColumnReference>
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Else>
                            </IF>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </TopExpression>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="4055" EstimateCPU="0.00284444" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="100" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sequence Project" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0322701">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="id" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="message" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="date" />
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <RunTimeInformation>
                            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="147" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                          </RunTimeInformation>
                          <SequenceProject>
                            <DefinedValues>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
                                <ScalarOperator ScalarString="row_number">
                                  <Sequence FunctionName="row_number" />
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </DefinedValue>
                            </DefinedValues>
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="4055" EstimateCPU="0.00071111" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="100" LogicalOp="Segment" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Segment" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0322621">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="id" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="message" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="date" />
                                <ColumnReference Column="Segment1008" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <RunTimeInformation>
                                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="147" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                              </RunTimeInformation>
                              <Segment>
                                <GroupBy />
                                <SegmentColumn>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="Segment1008" />
                                </SegmentColumn>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="4047" EstimateCPU="0.347654" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="100" LogicalOp="Filter" NodeId="5" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Filter" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0322601">
                                  <OutputList>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="id" />
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="message" />
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="date" />
                                  </OutputList>
                                  <RunTimeInformation>
                                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="147" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                                  </RunTimeInformation>
                                  <Filter StartupExpression="false">
                                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="4047" EstimateCPU="0.434724" EstimateIO="9.53275" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1111.11" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="6" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0312823" TableCardinality="395061">
                                      <OutputList>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="id" />
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="message" />
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="date" />
                                      </OutputList>
                                      <RunTimeInformation>
                                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="395061" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                                      </RunTimeInformation>
                                      <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="BACKWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                                        <DefinedValues>
                                          <DefinedValue>
                                            <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="id" />
                                          </DefinedValue>
                                          <DefinedValue>
                                            <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="message" />
                                          </DefinedValue>
                                          <DefinedValue>
                                            <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="date" />
                                          </DefinedValue>
                                        </DefinedValues>
                                        <Object Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Index="[PK_debug]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                                      </IndexScan>
                                    </RelOp>
                                    <Predicate>
                                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[timeflex].[dbo].[debug].[message] like [@Filter]">
                                        <Intrinsic FunctionName="like">
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Identifier>
                                              <ColumnReference Database="[timeflex]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[debug]" Column="message" />
                                            </Identifier>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Identifier>
                                              <ColumnReference Column="@Filter" />
                                            </Identifier>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </Intrinsic>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Predicate>
                                  </Filter>
                                </RelOp>
                              </Segment>
                            </RelOp>
                          </SequenceProject>
                        </RelOp>
                      </Top>
                    </RelOp>
                    <Predicate>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Expr1002]&gt;CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@Page]*(200)-(200),0) AND [Expr1002]&lt;=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@Page]*(200),0)">
                        <Logical Operation="AND">
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Compare CompareOp="GT">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1006">
                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                      <Convert DataType="bigint" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                          <Arithmetic Operation="SUB">
                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                              <Arithmetic Operation="MULT">
                                                <ScalarOperator>
                                                  <Identifier>
                                                    <ColumnReference Column="@Page" />
                                                  </Identifier>
                                                </ScalarOperator>
                                                <ScalarOperator>
                                                  <Const ConstValue="(200)" />
                                                </ScalarOperator>
                                              </Arithmetic>
                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                              <Const ConstValue="(200)" />
                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                          </Arithmetic>
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                      </Convert>
                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                  </ColumnReference>
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Compare CompareOp="LE">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1002" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1007">
                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                      <Convert DataType="bigint" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                          <Arithmetic Operation="MULT">
                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                              <Identifier>
                                                <ColumnReference Column="@Page" />
                                              </Identifier>
                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                              <Const ConstValue="(200)" />
                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                          </Arithmetic>
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                      </Convert>
                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                  </ColumnReference>
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Logical>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Predicate>
                  </Filter>
                </RelOp>
              </Sort>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@Page" ParameterRuntimeValue="(1)" />
              <ColumnReference Column="@Filter" ParameterRuntimeValue="'%ZUser888%'" />
            </ParameterList>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: How do you know the problem is the `row_number()` and not the `like`?  Also, in more recent versions of SQL Server, you can use `OFFSET`/`FETCH` for pagination.

Comment: That is going to scan all 220K entries. The ROW_NUMBER is not the bottleneck, however, 30+ seconds is way to much time for the query in my opinion.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In my case, it's `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (RTM-CU14) (KB3158271) - 12.0.2569.0 (X64)   May 27 2016 15:06:08   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)`, but it has to work on at least 2010, 2012, 2014 and 2016. Also, I wrote "the filtering and row numbering", with "filtering" being the LIKE.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan?

Comment: @RossBush . . . A column called `message` could be much larger than you might be thinking.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - Yes, I see, it is a TEXT column. It could be HUGE. I was thinking small strings.

Comment: @RossBush That column should be about 350 chars on average.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, don't use `text`, use `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`. It is officially deprecated in SQL Server 2016, so it might disappear in a future version.

For pagination, use `OFFSET`/`FETCH`. This was introduced in SQL Server 2012, so it is somewhat back compatible. There is no SQL Server 2010. Read about it [here](http://dbadiaries.com/new-t-sql-features-in-sql-server-2012-offset-and-fetch).

Let me eliminate table/page/row contention as the cause of the performance problem. My best guess is the `like` on a very wide column. If `message` really is a bunch of free form text, then use a full text index. The place to start is the documentation. For some reason, my links to Microsoft documentation aren't working well right now, but it is should be easy to find.

If the row width really is very wide, then you may have an additional problem with the `select *`. If you are doing paging, then this is likely for a user interface, so you might want to limit the columns to those that you really need -- and even shorten really long ones if you don't intend to show the entire column.

Comment: OK, I got 2010 wrong, it's 2008 that we still support.